# Django - Format a calculated interval

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-templates

**Model**

```
class Session(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    def duration(self):
        return self.end_time - self.start_time
```

**Template**

```
{{ session.duration|date:"H:i" }}
```

The duration can be displayed but seems not formattable. An idea why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In django templates you can use [timesince](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#timesince) and [timeuntil](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#timeuntil) filters for the same purpose. Both take two dates as an input and return the difference in a readable format.